# Não exibe aviso após enviar a mensagem

Tags: php, javascript, email, smtp

Preciso de uma dica: Estou com um problema no código PHP com a exibição de um aviso após o envio de mensagem. A mensagem é enviada sem problemas, mas nenhum aviso é exibido. Nem para o sucesso nem para o erro.
Segue o código PHP:

```
<?php

    if (!$mail->Send()) {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('".$nome."! Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');</script>";
        echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=index.php">';


    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Houve um erro! \nFavor tente mais tarde.');</script>";
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: da uma arrumada no Código!

Comment: Obrigado, Aderbal. Sim organizei o código, me achei e consegui resolver! Abs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que vc pretende fazer é algo relativamente simples, mas é necessário saber como está realizando essa tarefa, se tem algum esquema como mvc ou se está fazendo de forma procedural, se está realizando no mesmo arquivo ou se está direcionando a action para outro arquivo.
Mas vou tentar presumir que está utilizando de um método procedural e que está realizando a tarefa no mesmo arquivo.
Antes de tudo recomendo a trabalhar seus alerts como bootstrap e quando estiver mais experiente use o Alertsweet e deixe essas informações exibidas de forma mais profissional e estilizadas.

Ok, vamos ao código.
Use apenas a declaração em um escopo javascript e poderá fazer toda a tarefa da seguinte forma.

```
echo "<script> alert('".$nome."! Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!');
window.reload(); </script>"
```

Caso queira ser direcionado para outra página usando ainda o javascript após exibição do alert, substitua `window.reload()` por `window.location.href`, exp: redirecionar para a página do google `window.location.href= "https://google.com.br";`, se não usar o identificador de indereçamento http ou https, o código irá interpretar que a string faz parte de seu projeto e irá tentar buscar nele como uma basta ou arquivo, isso poderá ser útil se estiver validando em outro arquivo o seu envio de e-mail.
Recomendo que vc veja para iniciar os seus estudos o PHPMailer para envio de e-mails, o envio do nativo do php é muito ineficiente em ambiente de produção não tem investimento de pessoas empenhadas em sua melhoria a muito tempo.
Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!

Comment: Ôpa, Junior Silva. Muito obrigado pelas dicas, me ajudou muito ma resolução e reflexão! Abs

Comment: De nada amigo, fico feliz com sua em ajudar.